# How to change window size from script?

Tags: python, scripting, linux

I'm trying to set my window to full screen/maximised mode
[image]

How do I achieve this via script?

I tried [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/142561/131649) answer but it's obviously for windows operating system
whereas I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-change-window-size-from-script/1408174/2?u=cakelover), specifically:

```
bpy.ops.wm.window_fullscreen_toggle()
```

[image]

To check if already in fullscreen, see [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/206218/131649)